# Java: transform Long Timestamp + int offset to readable format

Tags: java, timestamp, timezone-offset

I'm trying to convert a `Long` timestamp with an offset (int) into a more readable format. So for example I have `1514564669355` as a timestamp with offset equal to `360`. How should I go about transforming this into the equivalent date format using java?

In this case the timestamp would be stored in UTC, so with the offset I'm looking to converting it to whatever timezone it needs. Thanks for any help/tips.

Comment: sure of youre timestamp ? What date it is supposed to be ?

Comment: Its a Unix timestamp stored in DynamoDB, you can use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert it. I'm jsut not sure how to handle these in Java with an int offset.

Comment: I'm not used to "offset" in timestamp, what is it ?

Comment: The offset would be used to convert the timestamp to a certain timezone. Each timezone has its own offset.

Comment: If you can, for presentation to a user in a given time zone, get a proper time zone like Asia/Almaty or Asia/Urumqi rather than just an offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Question is not clear.

- Perhaps you mean you have a value in UTC and want to adjust it to an offset of 360 minutes ahead of UTC. (A poor way to communicate a moment in time.)
- Or perhaps you meant the given value is already ahead of UTC. (An even worse way to communicate a moment in time.)

## Starting with UTC

First parse your input number. We will assume that number is a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_514_564_669_355L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-12-29T16:24:29.355Z

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is a number of hours, minutes, and seconds ahead of, or behind, [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Perhaps your Question’s mention of an offset of 360 is meant to be 360 minutes, or 6 hours ahead of UTC.

The `ZoneOffset` class cannot be instantiated from a number of minutes over 59. So we convert from 360 minutes to a total number of seconds.

```
int seconds = ( int ) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 360L ) ;  // Convert minutes to seconds.
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds( seconds );   // Determine offset-from-UTC.
```

> offset.toString(): +06:00

Adjust our `Instant` in UTC to this offset, yielding a `OffsetDateTime` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time. So the time-of-day is seen as 10 PM rather than as 4 PM since ( 16 + 6 ) = 22.

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-12-29T22:24:29.355+06:00

## Starting with offset

Perhaps you meant the moment being communicated is a count of milliseconds from UTC but then the number of milliseconds in 360 minutes has already been added or subtracted.

By the way, this is a very bad way to exchange date-time values. Educate the supplier of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Let's undo that addition/subtraction of an offset, to get back to UTC.

```
long millisInOffset = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 360L );  // Convert minutes to milliseconds.
long millisSinceEpoch = ( 1_514_564_669_355L - millisInOffset );
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-12-29T10:24:29.355Z

See that value in the offset sent to us.

```
int seconds = ( int ) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds( millisInOffset );
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds( seconds );
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );
System.out.println( odt );
```

> 2017-12-29T16:24:29.355+06:00

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).